# How can I replace this lamp socket?

Tags: electrical

I am trying to replace a single switch lamp socket to a 3 way switch but I am having trouble getting to the wires on the original socket. The terminals where the wires are attached are not visible and there are no visible screws. Is there a way to get to the wires on the socket in the attached pictures?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They are most likely "quick-wired", like the back-stab connections on the back of cheap receptacles.

WITH THE CORD UNPLUGGED, look to see if there are small holes or slots next to where the wire is stuck in. Open a paper clip and insert it into those holes/slots. This should release the wires.

Comment: That works, but even it the release holes were there i'd probably just cut... unless you expect to reuse the one-way socket someday (and it's a cheap enough part that you might not want to bother adding it to the spare parts collection).

Answer (score 1):

The socket that you show has the wires attached by one of two methods. They may be riveted or electro welded to the internal socket contacts. Or more likely they are fitted into poke in spring retainer terminals.

In either case I suggest that you simply cut off the existing wires at the socket and then re-strip the ends and attach to the new socket. Obviously purchase the new replacement socket of the type that has screw terminals. Most general purpose replacement ones come that way.